# Change an excel drop down value based on selections in other drop downs

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, dropdownlist

I am trying to create a template for Risk Analysis Matrix. I have 3 drop downs in 3 columns:

```
 Column A Called "Risk Severity"  with values (ACCEPTABLE, TOLERABLE,UNDESIRABLE,INTOLERABLE). 
 Column B called "Risk Likelihood" with values (IMPROBABLE,POSSIBLE,PROBABLE)
```

and my last

```
 column C is a drop down with "Risk Level" with values (LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH,EXTREME).
```

What I want is based on the selection the user makes in column A"Risk Severity" and Column B "Risk Liklihood" to change the value in column C drop down.

For E.g

```
If A = Acceptable and B= Improbable then C should be Low. 
If A = Acceptable and B= Possible then C should be Low
IF A = Intolerable and B= Probable then C should be extreme
```

so on and so forth.

All in all I will end up with 12 combinations(4*3) and 4 different values in column C based on those 12 combinations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional "parameters table" with the values C should take giving A and B values, like (sorry, hardcore to do tables in here) :

- A&B | C
- 10  | 1
- 01  | 0

In your case and with your own values this table should have 12 rows.

Then enter this formula into C drop down cell, where A and B are the input drop down cells :

C = VLOOKUP (A & B; PARAM_TABLE; 2; 0)

Because you concatenate the two values, there is only one possible combination giving the wanted C value.

I'm not sure if it is very useful to have a drop down for C cell as you'll always have one single value, unless I missed something.

Let me know if this answered your question !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want a drop-down (data validation) for the C column, but you can use an IF statement like this one to set the valid values in the C column if you wish.

=IF((Severity="ACCEPTABLE") * (Likelihood="IMPROBABLE"),"LOW","")

Naturally, you would have 12 different IF statements for the 12 possible combinations of Severity and Likelihood.